# What does it mean for a virtual function to be constant?

Tags: c++

I ask this because the terminology can be a bit misleading. If it's constant, it cannot be redefined in the derived classes. However, if it's virtual or better yet pure virtual, it's expected/required to be overridden in the derived classes.

So, what happens here?

Comment: If you mean the `const` that comes after the parameter list, that's not what it means at all.

Comment: Const means it cannot modify any members.

Comment: I think I got it mixed up with Java's final.

Comment: In Java, if a function is declared final, it cannot be overridded in the derived classes, is there something similar in C++?

Comment: The `const` keyword does not mean "constant". `const` means read-only. "Constant" usually refers to something that can be (and in some cases must be) evaluated at compile time. For example, this: `const int r = rand();` is perfectly legal; `r` is `const` but not constant.

Comment: @Grendan, Yes, and C++ has `final` for that deriving/overriding purpose, too.

Comment: @chris: So, the C++'s final means exactly what it does in Java?

Comment: I try to improve, but whenever I learn new stuff, I keep forgetting the old stuff. Last month I had a good grasp on const keyword in C++. :(

Comment: I don't think that C++ has final as a keyword.

Comment: @Grendan, Something's nagging at me that there's some small difference, but it is in general, except it has nothing to do with constness in C++.

Comment: @quamrana, Strictly speaking, it isn't a keyword, but it does exist.

Comment: @chris, not in C++ it doesn't.

Comment: @quamrana You need a newer C++ compiler.

Comment: @quamrana, Here's a respected [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final).

Comment: I've already looked that up just to check. Perhaps the question needs a different tag?

Answer (score 6):

Functions are never "constant". Non-static member functions can be `const`. That doesn't mean they can't be overridden.

A `const` member function is one that you are allowed to invoke on a `const` object, and it must not modify the object's non-mutable members or call non-`const` member functions on the same object. A `const` virtual function can be overridden by a `const` function with the same name and parameter types in a derived class.

A function that cannot be overridden is marked `final`. This is orthogonal to `const`ness.

Comment: I see my mistake. Thanks. So, there's a keyword final in c++ too like there's in Java?

Comment: @Grendan There is if you use a modern compiler (that supports C++11). However, I believe that `final` is rarely needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` modifier means the object is not modified by the method and the `this` pointer is `const`. Nevertheless, `mutable` members remain modifiable.